# Unable to connect to Sharepoint via Logicapps

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

When trying to access a client's data from a link they gave from SharePoint logicapps says:

> Error code: 'Unauthorized', Message: 'Unable to access the Folder in the dataset

On the same user from where I'm trying to access the data, I have access to everything except in Logic apps.
I created the below trigger and action to achieve this (see attached pic).

[image]

Can someone with a bit more knowledge on the subject maybe assist?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, it looks like the authentication is getting failed from the SharePoint end.
First of all, please make sure your access rights are in order again.
Then, please try to recreate the flow in a different browser or computer and see if the problem exists.